# How can i make the user make another choice when choosing a movie?

Tags: java, arrays, multiple-choice

I am writing a program where the user has a choice of 7 movies to buy. The user can choose as many movies up to 7 and than will add up the prices of the movies and than print the total price. I must use arrays in my program. My problem is when the user has already chosen their first movie they are given a choice if they want to buy another movie. I'm confused on how I should code my program by giving the user another choice to choose more than 1 movie. I need help on how I should fix my problem because when I run my program I it won't let me have the choice to choose another movie. Here my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MovieHits {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Declare Variables
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice = 0;
    String choice;
    int priceTotal = 0;
    int [] number = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

    String [] Movie = new String [7];
    int [] movieCost ={ 5, 4, 3, 6, 4, 4, 3}; 

    Movie [0] = "Iron Man";
    Movie [1] = "Transformers";
    Movie [2] = "Godzilla";
    Movie [3] = "Fast and Furious";
    Movie [4] = "Captain America";
    Movie [5] = "X Men";
    Movie [6] = "Rio";

    //Welcome the user
    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to TC Movies OnDemand.");

    //Display the listed movies so the user can know with movie they want to watch
    System.out.println("\nChoose which movie you want to watch: ");
    for ( int index = 0; index < 7; index = index + 1 ) 
    {
        System.out.println(number[index]+ ": " +  Movie[index]); 
        System.out.println("\t" + "Price: $" + movieCost[index]);
    }


    //Switch Statement to give user a menu to choose a movie
    userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (userChoice)
    {
    case 1: 
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[0] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[0]);
        break;

    case 2:
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[1] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[1]);
        break;

    case 3:
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[2] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" +  movieCost[2]);
        break;

    case 4:
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[3] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[3]);
        break;

    case 5:
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[4] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[4]);
        break;

    case 6:
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[5] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[5]);
        break;

    case 7:
        System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[6] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[6]);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("I'm Sorry you did not chose a movie.");
        break;
    }


    //Tell the user if they want to get another movie
    System.out.println("Do you want to add another movie. Enter Yes or No");
    choice = keyboard.next();

    do 
    {
        priceTotal = movieCost[userChoice];

    }
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
    {

    }
    //Tell the user the total price 




}
```

}

Comment: the `do-while` loop is in the wrong place

Comment: put `do {` before `userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();`.

Answer (score 3):

I would clean your code up like this:

```
String choice = "Yes"; //Set to yes by default.
//Welcome the user
System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to TC Movies OnDemand.");

while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
//Display the listed movies so the user can know with movie they want to watch
System.out.println("\nChoose which movie you want to watch: ");
for ( int index = 0; index < 7; index = index + 1 ){
    System.out.println(number[index]+ ": " +  Movie[index]); 
    System.out.println("\t" + "Price: $" + movieCost[index]);
}

userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

try{
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[userChoice] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[userChoice]);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Sorry, you did not choose a movie.");
}

//Tell the user if they want to get another movie
System.out.println("Do you want to add another movie? Enter Yes or No.");
choice = keyboard.next();

}
```

This refactors your code, meaning you don't have to have to use a long `switch` statement for every single movie type you have.

We've used `userChoice` as the actual index to look for, and the `try{}catch{}` block means that we still can 'catch' invalid input if the user incorrectly enters a movie to watch.

I originally was using a `do-while` like you had, but that structure never works for me, so I swapped it for a straight-forward `while` loop that I'm more familiar with.

Comment: @KickButtowski How so?

Comment: when I run it,it just asks once and program terminates :)

Comment: Agh! That's what I get for using a data structure I never use in real life. Editing...now.

Comment: it is k, but you still have same issue. :)

Comment: @KickButtowski, not sure what issue. I ran this code on my machine, and it runs until you tell it anything except for the word "Yes".  You need to have the OP's original code there, and insert my code into the body of it, making sure that `choice` has the initial value of "Yes".

Comment: you should change message in your catch block to something more useful like the number of films are not more than seven or something like that. Just one point to your awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
            //Switch Statement to give user a menu to choose a movie
            System.out.println("Choose your movie number:");
            userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();

            switch (userChoice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[0] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[0]);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[1] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[1]);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[2] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[2]);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[3] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[3]);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[4] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[4]);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[5] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[5]);
                    break;

                case 7:
                    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[6] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[6]);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("I'm Sorry you did not chose a movie.");
                    break;
            }

            //Tell the user if they want to get another movie
            System.out.println("Do you want to add another movie. Enter Yes or No");
            choice = keyboard.next();

            priceTotal = movieCost[userChoice];

        } while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro im going try to fix my program and see what i get thanks for the advice.

Comment: Now i have another problem when it i enter yes for the choice to get another movie it reprints the same test that i got for my first choice

Answer (score 0):

You should use the do-while loop as follows:

- In the do block, put the code that you would like to happen

  - This should be everything between (and including) "Choose the movie" and retrieving user's choice for repetition.
  - This means that all of that code is guaranteed to occur once, and will occur again if while condition is met.
- The code block for the while condition is above it, and thus is terminated with a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

```
You used do-while loop in wrong place in wrong way.Change Your code to this :

  do{
    try{ 
      userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
    } catch(Execption e){
         System.out.Println("Error in input!");
    }
switch (userChoice)
{
case 1: 
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[0] + "\nPrice is: " +   "$" + movieCost[0]);
    break;

case 2:
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[1] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[1]);
    break;

case 3:
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[2] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" +  movieCost[2]);
    break;

case 4:
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[3] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[3]);
    break;

case 5:
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[4] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[4]);
    break;

case 6:
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[5] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[5]);
    break;

case 7:
    System.out.println("The movie you have chosen is " + Movie[6] + "\nPrice is: " + "$" + movieCost[6]);
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("I'm Sorry you did not chose a movie.");
    break;
}


  //Tell the user if they want to get another movie

     try{ 
        System.out.println("Do you want to add another movie. Enter Yes or No");
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();
    } catch(Execption e){
         System.out.Println("Error in input!");
    }
    priceTotal = movieCost[userChoice];

} while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));
```